# AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo returns nil on ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

```
- (void)setupScanningSession {
// Initalising hte Capture session before doing any video capture/scanning.

NSError *error;

self.captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
self.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

// Set camera capture device to default and the media type to video.
AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
// Set video capture input: If there a problem initialising the camera, it will give am error.
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:captureDevice error:&error];

if (!input) {
    NSLog(@"Error connecting camera: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return;
}
// Adding input souce for capture session. i.e., Camera
[self.captureSession addInput:input];
```

the captureDevice is always **nil** when I try to run the app on the real device. The iPad is a A1474 with iOS 12.

The same piece of code runs perfectly on my iPhone 8.

Comment: I suspect it might be related to the chosen sessionPreset. Can you try another one ?

Answer (score 0):

After pulling my hair over this, I finally found. I was working with an iPad that was managed by my company and the camera was disabled by the management profile. After deleting this profile, the iOS inbuild camera app also appeared again.

The call of defaultDeviceWithMediaType was not nil anylonger.

Maybe this is helpful for someone else who finds this.